# Asp.net:show loading image before page loads for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

i am trying to display a loading image when the page is loading.Here is my code.

```
<body onunload="doHourglass();" onbeforeunload="doHourglass();" onload="setTimeout('show()',2000);">
<div id="divWait" style="display:none" >
      <h1>wait...</h1>
  </div>

<div id="main" style="display:none">
<asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" OnClick="code behind handler"
<div/>
<script>
function doHourglass()
{
console.log("inside dohour glass");
var divwait=document.getElementById('divWait');
 var divmainpage=document.getElementById('main');
 divmainpage.style.zIndex="0";
 divwait.style.zIndex="1";
 divwait.style.display='inline';
divmainpage.style.display='none';
setTimeout("show()",2000);
}
function show()
{
console.log("inside show");
var divwait=document.getElementById('divWait');
 var divmainpage=document.getElementById('main');
 divmainpage.style.zIndex="1";
 divwait.style.zIndex="0";
 divwait.style.display='none';
divmainpage.style.display='inline';
}
</script>
</body>
```

Problem is, it is not working when the page is loading for the first time.when i checked using console.log() i see for the first time control is not going inside doHourGlass() function.but for button click event it is working perfectly.

**Things i tried**:checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136705/javascript-before-onload) on SO, but i am not putting static html.I am trying to get the id of an html element and then working on that element so i can not use that solution.

**Edit**:one way i found is to keep divwait visible and hide main division then show main div when the page loads.but this way i can only display static html.i want to be able to call a function when page is loading for first time.
what is happening?is there a way to achieve it?please guide me.

Comment: I don't see you calling `doHourglass()` anywhere other than the 2 inline handlers that fire when the page unloads.  You don't call it when the page is loading.

Comment: Just use `<body onload="document.getElementById('divWait').style.display = 'none;document.getElementById('main').style.display = block;'>`

Comment: onload will execute the javascript function after the page loads.not when page is loading.