# identify an element that shows briefly

Tags: html, css, developer-tools

I bug in my page shows an element I do not want, just briefly on start. It goes away far to quickly to be inspected in the traditional way with right click and inspect. How do you identify such an element?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding break points in the developer console.  If it's an element that's instantiated via javascript you should be able to pause and identify it there.

[How to do this in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints?hl=en)

[How to do this in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint)

Comment: I disabled JS before trying to set a break point, but and the element still shows :(

Comment: I don't think you want to disable JS if you're attempting to test if it is causing this issue. Try a breakpoint at [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) or if that doesn't catch it try [setting one in a script tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136705/javascript-before-onload)